# Why is my regular expression combining capture groups from different lines

Tags: regex

I have the following regular expression:

```
(?<prefix>\S*?)\h*(?<score>\d+[+-]?)\s*(?<suffix>.*?(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})[A-Z]{2}\d{2})
```

The expression works fine when the target text includes each of the three capture groups, but produces strange results when that is not the case.  For example the following text yields these results:

```
^15+ vwu&ob12Ai18 => This one works. All three groups 

^15+  => This does not produce a match

vwu&ob12Ai18  => This does not produce a match

15+ vwu&ob12Ai18 =>  This one works - matching the 2nd and 3rd capture group.
```

Prefix - should match a variety of characters at the beginning of the string. In this example its the carat, but other potential characters include: . = F G ~ to name a few. There is a specific list of characters for the prefix.

Figure - is a one or two digit number optionally followed by nothing, a plus sign (+), a  minus sign (-) or a double quote (").

Suffix - The suffix is everything else. There is a specific list of characters for the suffix.

I have a sample at [Regex 101](http://regex101.com/r/sF2wV7/1). Note - The regex 101 sample seems to combining lines to create matches, but if you view the strings one at a time you will get the same results as above.

My question is how should I change my regular expression so that I can match each of the sample strings above.

Updated:  I've spent some more time on Regex 101 and have come up with an regular expression that is performing a bit better than the original.  This is more of a brute force approach as it does not include a non-capture group.

```
^(?<prefix>[\^\s])?(?<figiure>[\d+-\s]{0,5})?\s?(?<suffix>[vwu&ob1\dAi]{0,19})?$
```

I'm guessing there is a more elegant solution, but at least this is a step in the right direction.

Comment: Without an exact description which of your sample lines should match which string parts into which groups it's a *bit* difficult to build the correct expression. I'm guessing `vwu&ob12Ai18` should always be the suffix?

Comment: @tomalak I will edit the question and try to provide more detail. Thanks.

Comment: While you're at it, explain the difference between *prefix* and *suffix*, because they are both unspecific in your original regex, so when they are both optional there is no way to differentiate between the two.

Comment: Also explain what combinations are possible. Most importantly, can there be a *prefix* and a *suffix* but no *figure*?

Comment: Here are the valid combos: 1. Prefix + Figure, 2. Figure Only, 3. Prefix + Figure + Suffix, 4. Figure + Suffix and 5. Suffix Only.

Comment: Can the prefix contain numbers? I'm guessing no.

Comment: You are correct, the prefix can not contain a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your's (`x` mode):

```
(?<prefix>\S*?)\h*
(?<score>\d+[+-]?)\s*
(?<suffix>.*?(?:[A-Z]{2}|\d{2})[A-Z]{2}\d{2})
```

(Probably) correct *(we've determined [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65250/discussion-between-tomalak-and-mutuelinvestor) the the regex engine used is VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5, so no named groups)*:

```
^
(\D+?(?=\d+["+-]?[ ]))?
(\d+["+-]?[ ])?
(.*)
```

http://regex101.com/r/sF2wV7/6

Things to do when you match a line:

- before: add a space to the end (this is actually quite important)
- after: trim the contents of the individual groups

Comment: Wow, that was fast.  Thank you. What is X mode?

Comment: `x` is the "ignore whitespace" flag, it allows you to break the regex over multiple lines and even add comments to it by treating all literal whitespace in the expression as irrelevant.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about the regex yet. Take it with a grain of salt, I'm still tinkering on it.

Comment: Thanks for all help, really appreciate it.

Comment: @Mutuelinvestor I'm thinking [version 5](http://regex101.com/r/sF2wV7/5) should be pretty darn close. The key point is to use a look-ahead to make a subsequent *image* match a requirement for *prefix*. This way we can be unspecific about both *prefix* and *suffix* because we know that the *image* is the separator.

Comment: Could I trouble one last tine and ask that you break down your comment about the image match and look ahead. I'm a little out of my depth. Thanks again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65250/discussion-between-tomalak-and-mutuelinvestor).

Comment: I had an opportunity to go through your handy work in detail this morning.  Thanks again for truly elegant and efficient solution that I actually understand.